# Extracting sparse graphs from PDF files?

Tags: python, pdf, graph

I've been working on extracting images from text files. It works well for dense images such as [in this pdf on cats](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ArnSHhjciafhJDgT9BcOqd2OcCiltZMH/view?usp=sharing).

However, using libraries such as PyMuPDF Pillow, I have been unable to extract sparser images such as [the graphs in this pdf on linear regression](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hDL97aVLCPP6BEjPovc4DN_A0r3z2ZPh/view?usp=sharing).

I've tried some of the table extraction tools such as 'tabula', 'camelot' but those are best for data organized in a table.

Comment: Ok, thanks, @K J -- I will try that

Comment: Hi @K J, I'm assuming the same challenges would arise from trying to extract math formulas from PDFs. I tried what you suggested for both obtaining simple graphs and formulas and it's quite difficult as you mentioned. When I view the entire PDF it's not clear where the graphs are vs. where the text is from looking at the raw coded file

Comment: Thanks so much @K J. This is an interesting problem. get it: "no easy way to turn Lead into Gold" that makes sense:) thanks again

Comment: Thank a ton @K J  I took a look at this - it seems like you can turn a PDF page into an SVG but perhaps, not find an SVG that's embedded in the PDF.

Comment: Thanks @K J. Appreciate all this insight

Comment: @KJ you should gather all of this into an answer.  Several of us would upvote that.  It's a very good exposition.

Comment: Thanks @TimRoberts and KJ. I posted a summary of my learnings from this very helpful thread [and KJ's illuminating comments]. I would say this is still an open problem for me, but one which I am closer to understanding the scope of the challenge

Answer (score 1):

KJ's comments above helped me recognize that a PDF in some ways is like a baked cake, and unwinding the PDF is a bit like trying to separate out the individual ingredients after the cake is baked.

As the comments suggested there are a lot of PDF tools such as https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF-Utilities that allow you [on some PDFs] to parse out elements of the PDF, however sparse graphs seemed especially difficult as some of them are built using latex, or in some way where the image is not easy to extract. KJ also suggested using mupdf.com/docs/manual-mutool-trace.html and tracing back through the PDF to unwind some of reams of SVG data [though also acknowledging that would be quite an undertaking].

My colleague and I did have the idea that we could remove all images, and text from a PDF and then analyze what was left, to start to identify where the graphs are and then from there work backwards to collect them, but I've sort of switched gears for now to try some alternative problems [before maybe looping back to this one].